# Using pyFM on the Frappe data set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use pyFM on the Frappe (http://baltrunas.info/data/CARS2_code.zip) dataset. The following is my code:

```
import numpy as np  
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer  
from pyfm import pylibfm  

def loadData(filename,path="datasets/"):  
    data = []  
    y = []  
    users=set()  
    items=set()  
    with open(path+filename) as f:  
            for line in f:  
            (user,movieid,rating,ts)=line.split('\t')  
            data.append({ "user_id": str(user), "movie_id": str(movieid)})  
            y.append(float(rating))  
            users.add(user)  
            items.add(movieid)  

    return (data, np.array(y), users, items)  

(train_data, y_train, train_users, train_items) = loadData("traindata.txt")  
(test_data, y_test, test_users, test_items) = loadData("testdata.txt")  
v = DictVectorizer()  
X_train = v.fit_transform(train_data)  
X_test = v.transform(test_data)  
fm = pylibfm.FM(num_factors=10, num_iter=100, verbose=True, task="regression", initial_learning_rate=0.001,learning_rate_schedule="optimal")  

fm.fit(X_train,y_train)  
preds = fm.predict(X_test)  
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error  
print("FM MSE: %.4f" % mean_squared_error(y_test,preds))
```

However, I get Deprecation warning on running this code and FM MSE as 0.0000.
How do I get the code to run correctly?

Comment: The problem might lie with the training dataset as it is an implicit dataset, containing ratings = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an implicit dataset contains only positive ratings, FM will not work on the dataset (it will give an error of 0.00). You would need to have negative instances (ex. rating = 0) for FM to work correctly (in a real world setting).